# Need help creating an exe from python script

Tags: python, exe

I am wanting to create an exe version of my python script so and I am using a friends computer to test.

The script creates a basic text editor which can load, save etc.
I am using http://www.py2exe.org/ to create the exe. and I have been using this tutorial:
http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial

Everything works fine on my computer but when I try to run it on my friends computer I get this error:

> "The version of this file is not compatible with the version of Windows youre running. Check your computers system information to see wether you need an x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) version of the program, and then contact the software publisher."

I have windows 7 64bit and my friend has windows 7 32bit I want it to be compatible with both.

Any help would be apreciated this is my first time trying anything like this.

Thanks
Tom

Comment: Ok, I did a bit of googleing and found this page - http://docs.python.org/distutils/builtdist.html so I tried running ("C:\..\python setup.py build --plat-name=win32") (from section 5.4) in the command line and it ran through and the exe still worked on my machine but I still get the same error as before on my friends computer.
So problem is still not solved, thanks for the help so far.

Answer (score 3):

You can either build both an x86 and x64 (32-bit and 64-bit) version, or you can build it only as a 32-bit version.

The 32-bit version will run on both 64-bit and 32-bit Windows systems.

Comment: Ok, but how do I make it a 32 or 64 bit version. As I said this is my first time doing this and I am a beginner with programing in general. I didn't know I had made a 64bit version.

Comment: I'm guessing, but in order to create a 32-bit version I think you would need to run py2exe using 32-bit Python.